# C++ How does if (system("CLS") {system("clear)} work

Tags: c++

C++ How does this work

```
if (system("cls"))
{
    system("clear");
}
```

I was trying to find a cross-platform way to clear the console in C++ and came across this and wanted to know how it works? Does it return an error if the command isn't found?

Comment: C and C++ are two very different languages. Please don't spam with tags, only tag the actually relevant tags, which means only the language-tag for the language you're actually program in.

Comment: It calls `system("cls")` and if that returns a non-zero value (ie: indicating an error), it calls `system("clear")`.

Comment: It runs the command in the shell if the first one fails it runs the other one. The first one `system("cls")` is for MS Windows while the other one is for many systems other than windows ( linux, macOS, bsd ...). With this said you may want to use the `ncurses` library instead of spawning a shell

Comment: `system` can be tricky. At least on unix-likes, if somebody has a different `cls` or `clear` in their path, this could do anything at all.

Comment: cls could be the name of some entirely different executable on a *nix computer for all we know, so writing code like this is not recommended.

Comment: Don't *ever* use `system()` - it is a security nightmare!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cls` and `clear` are terminal/command prompt commands used to clear the screen.

`system` is a c++ command used to interact with the cmd/terminal directly. It returns 0 if a command was completed successfully.

In this case, if `cls` fails to clear the screen (in other words, the system command returns something other than 0) then we issue the `clear` command via system.
One of those commands will work on the OS that the app is being run on.

Comment: "_One of those commands will work on the OS that the app is being run on_" or none of them.

Comment: Clear works on Linux/MacOS. Cls works on Windows.

Edit: Of course I'm talking about instances of the OS where the clear/cls commands weren't overriden to do something else.

Comment: @IlijaVuk: `clear` is from `/bin/bash`, I think, which might not be present in all Linux environments.

Comment: There are other OS's in the world outside of Linux, MacOS, and Windows; those OS's may not have either a `cls` or a `clear` shell command (or if they do have them, they may not do what this code intended).

Answer (score 0):

I’m probably the one who wrote that. Don’t use it.
<sup>(I never meant for people to be using it as an example of how to clear the screen. Pretty sure I said as much, too.)</sup>

These days, just use the VT-100 escape sequences:

```
void clear_screen()
{
  printf( 
    "\033[2J"       // clear the screen
    "\033[1;1H" );  // move cursor home
}
```

This is 100% cross-platform on any modern system: Windows, Linux, OS X... anything with a modern terminal emulator.